# How to use Kotlin/Native code with android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, kotlin-native

I have Kotlin/Native+C librarrie(s) code, that i want to as a part of Android and Linux app.

I hoped that Kotlin/Native can be easily reused on android. But couldn't find any way to use it, except build .so library and call it via JNI.
But in such case Kotlin/Native is uselless, and i can use C libraries via JNI.
Is i'm wrong and miss something?

Comment: Your summary is correct, Kotlin/Native would not make any help in this case. This technology aims to make it easier to use C libraries(with no JNI), on platforms where using jvm is not preferable. Mixing up Kotlin/JVM and Kotlin/Native compilers will only increase the complexity of the project.